# React/Typescript location.key is not unique

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend, crud, react-typescript

When I create CRUD forms in React/Typescript they merge with each-other because the keys of both are the same.

```
 return (
    <div className="App d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage} />
      <Route
        path={'/(.+)'}
        render={() => (
          <>
            <NavBar />
            <Container style={{ marginTop: '7em' }}>
              <Route exact path='/subject' component={SubjectDashboard} />
              <Route key={location.key} path={['/createSubject', '/manage/:id']} component={CountryForm} />
              <Route exact path='/departments' component={DepartmentDashboard} />
              <Route key={location.key} path={['/createDepartment', '/manages/:id']} component={DepartmentForm} />
            </Container>
          </>
        )}
      />
```

I tried location.pathname but still the same problem.
this only *works* if one of them is
**location.key**
and the other
**location.pathname** , but when I add the third CRUD form it breaks agian.

Answer (score 0):

If you've read the [React Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) regarding keys, you'd see that the key property is primarily used in scenarios where a list or collection of data need to be rendered and its used to determine which component has changed in that list.

So a `key` needs to be unique to that specific piece of data, if in the case of sibling components - which is what you have.

But `<Route />` component doesn't need a key to work. And in your case, since you're not rendering a list, then you don't really need it. You should be able to remove them and it'll work fine.

So these are my recommendations:

- Remove the key prop from both of those elements
- Or for whatever reason you need them in, use different values for them. Maybe append `-subject` and `-department` to `location.key` so `key={location.key + '-subject'}`